# Escondendo opção do menu de acordo com o tipo de usurário

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro com angularJS e C#, ao cadastrar um novo usuário existem dois tipos de usuários para se escolher, administrador e bibliotecário, sendo administrador tipo 1 e bibliotecário tipo 2. e um menu com as seguintes opções: condomínio, livro, morador e usuário, quando um usuário do tipo bibliotecário logar quero que a opção condomínio não esteja presente no menu, já criei um método para isso, porém gostaria de saber como usa-lo junto com o arquivo html do menu

Código do método:

```
public void UserType(string usuario)
{
    var db = new CRMEntities();
    object user;

    try
    {
        user = db.Usuario.Where(p => p.usuario1 == usuario).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        user = null;
    }

    var returnJson = "";

    if (user == null)
        returnJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(null);
    else
        returnJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(((Usuario)user).grupoUsuario);

    ReturnJson(returnJson);
}
```

Código do menu:

```
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li>
            <a href="#!/"><span class="nav-label">Painel</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">Cadastro</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="#!/condominio">Condom&iacute;nio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/livro">Livro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/morador">Morador</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/usuario">Usu&aacute;rio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Passa a informação pra sua model no `AngularJS` e usa a diretiva `ng-show`

Answer (score 0):

Vamos assumir que a sua página do menu é composta por uma componente, controlador, html e um .sass. Para este caso, o nome *vm* será o *controllerAs* da sua componente.

No seu controlador, deverá ter uma função que verifique se o utilizador é do tipo bibliotecário ou não. Vamos chamar esta função `verificarBibliotecario()`. Se for bibliotecário, retorna *true*, se não, retorna *false*.

Assim, é fácil 'esconder' a opção 'Condomínio' do menu inicial. Para tal, pode utilizar a diretiva **ng-show** no seu html:

```
<li ng-show="!vm.verificarBibliotecario()"><a href="#!/condominio">Condom&iacute;nio</a></li>
```

Assim, todos os utilizadores que não sejam bibliotecários poderão ver a opção do menu, enquanto que um bibliotecário não terá essa opção disponível.